# IBM Worklight 6.2 App - Remote Server communication failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am developing a hybrid app in Worklight 6.2. I have a WorkLight Server installed Red Hat Linux 6 base as remote server.

I have give the servers ip address, port number and context root as"/worklight" in the "build settings and deploy target".

Then i added my adapter file and wlapp file into the remote servers "app" folder. I haven't made any changes in the server.xml file.

Now when i call the procedure from my app i am getting "[IPADDRESS:PORT/worklight/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/query] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later."

What am i missing and What changes do i have to make to make the request to work.?

Comment: Why do you not use the Worklight Console belonging to the Worklight instance on your remote server to deploy the .wlapp and .adapter files? You shouldn't circumvent the system by placing files manually.

Comment: How would i get worklight console on the remote server. If i try to access localhost:9080/worklightconsole is says context root not found.

Comment: Please follow the documentation. Verify you have properly deployed Worklight in the remote server and make sure your setup is correct. By following the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you are describing are not clear.

Make sure you are following the steps as provided in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center.

1. First [make sure the Worklight Server deployment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_installation.html?lang=en) to the application server was done correctly
   You can verify this then by loading the Worklight Console (there will be no deployed projects)
2. Then follow the Worklight project (.war, .wlapp, .adapter) [deployment to the Worklight Server instructions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html?lang=en)
   You can verify this then by loading the Worklight Console (there will be 1 deployed application)

Comment: Thanks dude. Those links really made it work. Now need to check if this works in other OS's